# The new rupee symbol's unicode doesn't show up on the android emulator

Tags: android, unicode, android-emulator

The new Indian rupee symbol with unicode "\u20B9" doesn't show up on the android emulator but it gets printed perfectly on the Log file. What could be the reason? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's system font may not have our Indian currency symbol. You should use your own font embedded in you application to achieve this. and is required to support older versions of Android devices too.

You can download font from [here](https://phaven-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/files/unknown_part/asset/815393/4eky-byq_jGts5fB5RgLOO0b-nc/Rupee_Foradian.ttf) or from [here](https://www.karnataka.gov.in/Documents/Rupee_Foradian.ttf)

And follow this tutorial to know about font embedding : http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

Comment: link seems to be broken

Comment: @RishiDua thank you for pointing out. updated links in the answer